# Generic error when trying to save data

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing

we have just experienced a weird error on our applications connecting to a clustered Sql Server 2000: both our .NET applications (ADO.NET) and C++ (ADO) application get an error which we cannot explain.
All the applications can connect to the database, can read data from it but cannot write data on it, receiving a "Generic network error" (I've translated from the Italian message). After several trials, we tried to switch the services from one node to the other, and this seems to have solved the problem.
Still no one is able to figure out what happened and why; is there anybody who is able to explain to me?
Thanks in advance
Marco

---

EDIT:
Just in case it happens to someone else: we found out that the computer didn't have the last version of MDAC (2.8 SP1). It's very likely that the customer reinstalled the computer and didn't update Windows: when we ran Windows Update, the problem *magically* (from the customer point of view...) was fixed.
We don't know exactly which version of MDAC was installed, but could have been 2.6 or less, since I know our applications have problems with older versions of MDAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied any updates recently?

I have seen something similar on later versions of SQLServer so I would have a look at the security access to the server etc as I don't think they all replicate from system to system.

Comment: There SHOULD NOT have been any update lately, but I will check it out. Maybe I misunderstand your kind reply, but I already checked most common access issues (such as permissions), usng QueryAnalyzer to connect to the db with the same user/pwd and I succeeded.